# Flutter Table columns rendering strange when applying columnWidths

Tags: flutter, flexbox, flutter-layout

I'm using `Table` I have `defaultColumnWidth: IntrinsicColumnWidth()` and

```
columnWidths: {
  0: FlexColumnWidth(1),
  1: FlexColumnWidth(1),
  2: FlexColumnWidth(1),
  3: FlexColumnWidth(1),
}
```

the `TableRow` children are all `Text` widgets and it renders like the below image

[image]

If I remove `columnWidths` it's fine, but all the columns are right up against each other. I also tried `FractionColumnWidth(0.25)` but it got the same results as `FlexColumnWidth`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a constraints issue. I wrapped the `Table` in a `SizedBox` with a specific width and that fixed the problem.